# How can you test the Youtube API without pushing to your live production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, testing, youtube, youtube-api

Since the Youtube API requires that you run your files on a webserver rather than locally (http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#GettingStarted) how can you test the API without pushing it to your live production server?

I'm using Ruby on Rails hosted on Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: To test any of these calls, you must have your file running on a webserver, as the Flash player restricts calls between local files and the internet.

That does not sound like it needs to go to a *production* server. I am not familiar with Flash, but `http://localhost/test.html` (as opposed to `file://test.html`) probably works. And even if not, any old test server will do.

Comment: Ohhh so it doesn't matter whether it's a local server or not, it just means you cannot run the file directly?

Comment: That is how I read that note, but again, I am not familiar with Flash.

Comment: Your interpretation makes sense. I'll have to actually test it out before I accept your answer though.